# Using autofs with sshfs: "no such file or directory" error

Tags: automount, sshfs, autofs

After following instructions on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs, I am able to mount directory via sshfs as root, however, autofs doesn't work for me.

My `auto.master` contains

```
/media/sshfs /etc/auto.sshfs        uid=1000,gid=1000,--timeout=30 --ghost
```

and `auto.sshfs` has

```
remote1     -fstype=fuse,rw,nodev,nonempty,noatime,allow_other,max_read=65536 :sshfs\#me@host\:
```

`ls /media/sshfs/remote1` gives "No such file or directory".  Any hints on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Pay special attention to the manual page you referenced regarding 'copy your private key to /root/.ssh/" -- I received the same "no such file or directory" error until I added the private key. Once the key was added to /root/.ssh, my automount worked perfectly.